# Determine a moment when a client connects to and disconnects from an OpenVpn server

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn

Is there any way to determine a moment when a client connects to and disconnects from an OpenVpn server? Does OpenVpn provide the API for that? If not, how can I do that?

Comment: Detect on a client or on a server?

Comment: @techraf, on a server.

Answer (score 1):

OpenVPN, generally speaking, will send log output to syslog. Syslog, generally speaking, writes to `/var/log/syslog`. Check there first for OpenVPN lines. `grep` is your friend and wants to help you.

OpenVPN can be configured to log to an explicit location, however. For example: `log-append /var/log/openvpn.log` You may also want to tweak verbosity settings with the `verb #` option in OpenVPN's config files.

Comment: isn't there a more standard, easier way?

Comment: @Dorkajo There literally could not be a more standard, or easier way than this.

Comment: openvpn has api, why not?

Comment: how about "--client-connect [script]"?

Comment: so?.............

Comment: @Dorkajo You have my answer. Take it or leave it.

Comment: how about "--client-connect [script]"?

Comment: @Dorkajo Try it and find out. Report back.

Comment: who of us 2 smart admin: I or you?